# What does NextPage in Next.js do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

I just started using TypeScript with Next. What does this do?
`import { NextPage } from 'next';`
`export const Page: NextPage = () => {}`
I looked at the docs but it does really give a good explanation in what it does.

I am guessing by the name that it routes pages.
Can someone please explain what this does?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Usage of NextPage type in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623841/usage-of-nextpage-type-in-next-js)?

Comment: Its not next page, but Next™ Page

Answer (score 7):

My advice is to start [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html), but in brief:

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';

export const Page: NextPage = () => {}
```

NextPage is a type exported by NextJS. When we write `Page: NextPage` we're saying that our `Page` component is of type `NextPage`.

Comment: oh i see... we are assigning our page with types.... so everything that will be a Page(in JS) will be a NextPage in TS...

Comment: I've been learning React and NextJs and I see most people don't use this format.  Just create export default functions.  I only seen this in the NextJs MaterialUI example I'm working with now.  Can you tell me if there's any benefit of using the above? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`import { NextPage } from 'next';` : This line imports the NextPage type from the next package. The NextPage type is a generic type provided by Next.js for defining the type of a Next.js page component.

When you create a page in Next.js, you typically define it as a React component. The NextPage type is a type alias for a React component that is a Next.js page. It includes properties specific to Next.js pages, such as getStaticProps, getServerSideProps, and others used for data fetching during page rendering.

So, in summary, the code you provided is creating a Next.js page component using TypeScript. It is defining a constant named Page with the type NextPage and providing the logic for your page within the arrow function. This is a common pattern when working with Next.js and TypeScript to ensure type safety and provide better development tooling support.