# Usage of NextPage type in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js

Can anyone describe `NextPage` type in Next.js TypeScript project?

Every site just says that it is for type assigning in Next.js, but I wanna know why we should use it? What is the usage of it? Why should we use this instead of `React.Node` or `React.Fc`?

Answer (score 11):

To better understand the `NextPage` type, let's look at its type definition in Next.js.

```js
export type NextPage<P = {}, IP = P> = NextComponentType<NextPageContext, IP, P>
```

It's defined by another type `NextComponentType`, which in turn is defined as follows.

```js
export declare type NextComponentType<C extends BaseContext = NextPageContext, IP = {}, P = {}> = ComponentType<P> & {
    /**
     * Used for initial page load data population. Data returned from `getInitialProps` is serialized when server rendered.
     * Make sure to return plain `Object` without using `Date`, `Map`, `Set`.
     * @param ctx Context of `page`
     */
    getInitialProps?(context: C): IP | Promise<IP>;
};
```

This type extends React's `ComponentType` directly, and adds `getInitialProps` as an optional property.

Essentially, `NextPage` type allows to properly type page components which include [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) (not very common since the introduction of `getServerSideProps` though).

In the end, while you could use React's built-in types on a page component that doesn't include `getInitialProps` without issues, it's recommended to use the types provided by Next.js. It'll make your code more future-proof and idiomatic, in case anything gets added/removed at the framework level.

Comment: where are you getting that code? I searched the Next.js GitHub repo for `NextPage` and 0 results came up.

Comment: @javaandy From https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L63.

Comment: @juliomalves I've been using NextPage for long so I thought this was correct, but when I tried using Next 13 I get `Page "app/.../page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.` on build time. Have you encountered the same error?

Comment: @danikaze I would not recommend using the `NextPage` type with Next.js 13 `app` folder.

Comment: yeah I've been searching and... looks like it's not stable at all yet :-/ toob ad