# create-next-app produces JSX.Element is not assignable to variable type NextPage error

Tags: typescript, next.js, webstorm

I've just spun up a new project using `create-next-app` using TypeScript and my IDE (WebStorm) is showing this error in the default generated homepage.

> Initializer type () => JSX.Element is not assignable to variable type NextPage

[image: Screenshot from my IDE]

The project still builds and runs though when using `yarn dev`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've also experienced that error message, but after updating some of my tools — Next 12.1.4 and TypeScript 4.7.0 (I use nightly) — I haven't seen it since. I use a different JetBrains IDE than you do (IDEA Ultimate 2021.3.3) and something somewhere mysteriously fixed itself. Also, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636868/15115299

Comment: I'm already on Next 12.1.4. Currently using the latest stable Typescript (4.6.3). I can't use a pre-release version for this unfortunately :( ... did you have to make any changes in your IDE settings?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, the code you have is valid for the `NextPage` type. I'm not familiar with WebStorm IDE, but it's most likely an issue with its settings.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your issue and noticed the code in your screenshot is slightly different than what I'm seeing on my end (for example, my `index.tsx` file imports `Home.module.css`). This is the exact command I used — `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript my-app`. Did you use something similar?

Comment: I’ve removed the css module because I plan on using tailwind. You can see a sample tailwind css class in the screenshot but this issue was present from project creation. Since it does build I’m fairly sure it is a settings issue with webstorm not picking up the types correctly. Any idea why that might be? Never had this with webstorm before

Comment: I'd double-check the [TypeScript settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-languages-typescript.html#ws_settings_ts_typescript) and that directories like `pages`, `components`, `public`, etc. are [marked/categorized](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#content-root) correctly. Otherwise, you could try posting over at the [WebStorm Support Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm) and hope someone from JetBrains can chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly got these issues after reinstall Webstorm and need to reopen typescript language service in settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Home` is a React component type it as `React.FC` because at the end it is a react component.

```
const Home: React.FC<{}> = () => {

return (
    // ...
  )
}
```

It builds without error because it gets compiled/converted into `javascript`, and in javascript types and interfaces are omitted.

Comment: Why does create-next-app generate it as type NextPage then?

Comment: Try using above type. I think it's a webstorm IDE issue, I would suggest using VS Code for Next.

Comment: To be clear, this answer doesn't answer the question. I don't want to use VSCode, nor do I want to change the typing of my page components because NextPage<> is a valid type and should be used when working in NextJS. I use Webstorm as my IDE. This error should not be shown unless it is a real error and I'm asking, is it a real error and if so how to fix it so that NextPage works correctly and if it's not a real error what do I need to do in Webstorm to make it stop showing up as an error?