# Should you use React.FC to type your Next.js components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use a VScode extension "*React Typescript Snippets*" which have a snippet `tfcd` that gives   function component base with Typescript and default export.

```
import React from 'react';

type indexProps = {
    
};

const Layout:React.FC<indexProps> = () => {
    
    return <div>Have a good coding</div>
}
export default Layout;
```

I used it before with Next.js and it worked fine but I'm unsure if its worth changing `React.FC` with `NextPage` which I've seen more people use.

What's the difference between `React.FC` and `NextPage` and which one is the most correct to use for a Next.js project?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623841/usage-of-nextpage-type-in-next-js. I would personally choose to use NextPage.

Comment: @ColinHale Yes, that helps. `NextPage` it is then. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is absolutely fine to use React.FC!
The only thing you want to make sure of is that you type your page components in the /pages folder with NextPage, but the rest of your components in the /components folder can be typed with React.FC

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: This exactly what I wanted to hear, I like the snippet and I wanted to keep using it but didn't like changing the type everytime.

Comment: Gotcha!
Make sure to understand what is the difference between NextPage and React.FC type. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623841/usage-of-nextpage-type-in-next-js